# Filtered PIG data loaded twice?

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following PIG Script:

```
A = LOAD 'text_a.txt' USING PigStorage();
B = LOAD 'text_b.txt' USING PigStorage();
SOMETHING = FILTER A $0 matches 'SOMETHING';
FOOBAR = FILTER A $0 matches 'FOOBAR';

SOMETHING_B = JOIN SOMETHING BY key, B BY $1;
FOOBAR_B = JOIN FOOBAR BY key, B BY $1;
TEMP = JOIN SOMETHING_B BY key, FOOBAR_B by key;
OUT = FOREACH TEMP GENERATE SOMETHING_B::$1 - FOOBAR_B::$1; 
dump OUT;
```

When this script runs, it looks like the Data in A and B is read from the source twice?  Is there someway to prevent it from being read the second time?

Comment: Did you try to use the EXPLAIN command to display the execution plan and see if the data is really read twice ? [link](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#explain)

Comment: Running EXPLAIN now. now trying to figure out now to read the EXPLAIN Results

Answer (score 0):

First just have
"EXPLAIN OUT" at end of script to figure out that data is being read twice or not .

Looking at ur script dosent looks like A,B are being called twice